# How to safely upgrade quasar-framework to latest version

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar, webpack-5

In my project quasar-framework was being used with webpack 3 and vue 2.
I have updated webpack 3 to 5 and vue 2 to 3. But i am facing issue while upgrdaing quasar-framework to latest one.

I can see quasar-framework was published 4 years back and not compatible with webpack 5 anymore. So i decided to use quasar package 2.12.0 but it totally ruined my design.
I cant find some css like quasar.mat.styl in new version.
There are many quasar packages i am not which one to use.

I am kind of blocked here. Can anyone suggest the correct package to use ?

Comment: Is the code related to this project movable? I'm asking because it may be advantageous to look at creating a fresh project and moving the code -> configuring it to fit the folder/file structure than fix the dependencies